# populate combobox with databindings between entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, data-binding, combobox

I'm working on a Windows Forms application with Entity Framework Core and trying to populate a ComboBox with role names and bind it to the employee's role. However, despite trying various approaches, the ComboBox remains empty and doesn't display any role names.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    private void LoadEmployees(Employee? selectedEmployee)
    {
        _context.Employees.Load();
        _bindingSource = new BindingSource(_context.Employees.Local.ToBindingList(), null);
    }
    if (selectedEmployee != null)
    {
         _bindingSource.Position = _bindingSource.IndexOf(selectedEmployee);
    }
    
    private void LoadRoles()
    {
        var rolesList = _context.Roles.ToList();
        cbRole.DataSource = rolesList;
        cbRole.DisplayMember = "RoleName";
        cbRole.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
    
    private void SetupDataBindings(Employee? selectedEmployee)
    {
        // ... other bindings
    
        cbRole.DataBindings.Clear();
        cbRole.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _bindingSource, "Role.Id", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    
        // ... other bindings
    }
```

I've made sure that my Employee class has a Role property with a valid ID and the Role class has a RoleName property.

I've already tried inserting debug statements to ensure that my data source contains the roles and the bindings are set up correctly. However, the ComboBox remains empty. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?